# dynamic google map using php

Tags: php, google-maps

I want to archive this functionality of a dynamic map such when we select place then it will display in map

If we zoom the map then the list will also refresh such that it display only those places which are in current map

If we click on next 10 places it will load new map accordingly

By using what and how it is going to be possible for me to do that in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have to use Google Maps v3 JavaScript API. It's scriptable (as in dynamic) and can do everything you have described (together with PHP for data).

- Your *places* need to have geographical coordinates (latitude/longitude) stored in your db.
- Listen for map `bounds_changed` event and display a marker for every place that fits within map bounds (AJAX query, whatever).
- Update your list of places checking `map.getBounds()` bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read about

- [OpenLayers](http://www.openlayers.org/)
- [gMap](http://gmap.nurtext.de/)
- [jMapping](http://vigetlabs.github.com/jmapping/)

They are all helpfull for dynamic and static maps.

You may also see [this tutorial about Google Maps](http://marcgrabanski.com/article/jquery-google-maps-tutorial-basics).